# extracting deeply nested href in python with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract a very deeply nested href. The structure looks like this:

```
<div id="main">
 <ol>
   <li class>
     <div class>
       <div class>
         <a class>
         <h1 class="title entry-title">
           <a href="http://wwww.link_i_want_to_extract.com">
           <span class>
         </h1>
        </div>
       </div>
     </li>
```

and then there are bunch of other `<li class>` with hrefs within. 
So basically the parent to child order is

```
li - div - div - h1 - a href
```

I've tried the following:

```
soup.select('li div div h1')
```

also

```
soup.find_all("h1", { "class" : "title entry-title" })
```

also

```
for item in soup.find_all("h1", attrs={"class" : "title entry-title"}):
        for link in item.find_all('a',href=TRUE):
```

These all doesn't seem to work, I get `[]` or empty `.txt` files.

Plus, more disturbing is that after defining `soup` and then I do `print(soup)` I don't see the nested classes, I only see the one at the top, `<div id=main>` and also doing `print soup.l` is not retrieving the l classes. I don't think `Beautifulsoup` recognizes l classes and others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div id="main">
   <ol>
      <li class>
         <div class>
            <div class>
               <a class>
               <h1 class="title entry-title">
                  <a href="http://www.link_i_want_to_extract.com">
                  <span class>
               </h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class>
         <div class>
            <div class>
               <a class>
               <h1 class="title entry-title">
                  <a href="https://other_link_i_want_to_extract.net">
                  <span class>
               </h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ol>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
for h1 in soup.find_all('h1', class_="title entry-title"):
    print(h1.find("a")['href'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You had a typo: `href=TRUE`, should be `href=True`.

```
s = """
<div id="main">
   <ol>
      <li class>
         <div class>
            <div class>
               <a class>
               <h1 class="title entry-title">
                  <a href="http://www.link_i_want_to_extract.com">
                  <span class>
               </h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li>
      <li class>
         <div class>
            <div class>
               <a class>
               <h1 class="title entry-title">
                  <a href="https://other_link_i_want_to_extract.net">
                  <span class>
               </h1>
            </div>
         </div>
      </li>
   </ol>
</div>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all("h1", attrs={"class" : "title entry-title"}):
    for link in item.find_all('a',href=True):
        print('bs link:', link['href'])
```

Alternatively you can use [pyQuery](http://pythonhosted.org/pyquery/index.html), which offers a js/jquery like querying syntax:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
from lxml import etree

d = pq(s)
for link in d('h1.title.entry-title > a'):
    print('pq link:', pq(link).attr('href'))
```

Returns:

```
bs link: http://www.link_i_want_to_extract.com
bs link: https://other_link_i_want_to_extract.net
pq link: http://www.link_i_want_to_extract.com
pq link: https://other_link_i_want_to_extract.net
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know PyQuery yet!

Answer (score 0):

use `.` to find the first decendent:

```
soup.find('div', id="main").h1.a['href']
```

or use `h1` as an anchor:

```
soup.find("h1", { "class" : "title entry-title" }).a['href']
```

Comment: I'm getting AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'a'

Comment: @ppasler before you comment, test it first.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way:

```
soup.select('a[href]')
```

or:

```
soup.findAll('a', href=True)
```